# Base case when proving $P_{n} = P^{n}$ by induction (discrete time Markov chain)

Tags: stochastic-processes, induction, markov-chains, proof-explanation

Suppose that I want to prove $P_{n} = P^{n}$ for $n \geq 0$, $n \in \mathbf{N_{0}}$ where P is the transition matrix, by induction and $(X_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ is a discrete-time Markov chain.

Why is it that I can't make the base case $n = 0$ and instead have to do $n = 1?$ A thorough explanation would be much appreciated -- all I've got when I asked someone is that 'n = 0 is trivial'?

I can do the other parts regarding the induction hypothesis and using it for the rest of the proof.

Comment: Well if you define $P^0 = I$ then it works. You have that $\vec{\pi} P^0 = \vec{\pi} I = \vec{\pi}$ where $\vec{\pi}$ is the starting distribution. Note also that the definition that a matrix to the power $0$ makes senses in the sense that $M M^{-1} = M^0 = I$ using the standard definition of inverse matrix.

Comment: @Zubzub Yes, I know that it works but I've been told that my base case step should be for $n = 1$ and not for $n = 0$.